# CUDA Thrust: Finding the index of the first element in a vector satisfying a predicate (e.g., zero or negative) [Matlab's syntax min(find(x<=0))]

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I am attempting to find the the index of the first zero or negative value of an array using CUDA Thrust. The serial CPU code I am attempting to write using CUDA Thrust is the following:

```
for (int i = StartIndex; i <= ArrayLimitIndex; i++) 
{ 
    if (Array[i] <= 0) { DesiredIndex = i; break; } 
}
```

I am thinking that the easiest way to do this on the GPU will be using the `find_if` function within the Thrust library.

The array is already on the GPU and I am attempting to search for the index on this array using Thrust as such:

```
struct less_than_or_eq_zero
{
__host__ __device__
bool operator() (double x)
{
    return x <= 0;
}
};

thrust::device_vector<double>::iterator iter;
thrust::device_ptr<double> dev_ptr_Col46 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev_Col46);
iter = thrust::find_if(thrust::device, dev_ptr_Col46, dev_ptr_Col46 + size,less_than_or_eq_zero());
```

Now I would like to use the value of `iter` as an argument for my next kernel:

```
newKernel<<<size, 1>>>(*dev_array, iter)
```

where the `newKernel` definition is of the form:

```
__global__ void newKernel(double *dev_array, iter)
{
     int x = blockIdx.x;
     if(x <= iter)
     {
         //process data here...
     }
}
```

I know that the code I have here is incorrect and I have a few questions regarding the use of `iter`. First, `iter` is a `device_vector`. Is there any way I can make `iter` just one value and not a vector? Also, when I have executed the `find_if` how can I use the value of `iter` in my next kernel call?

Any help with this be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `iter` isn't a `device_vector` - it's a iterator pointing into a `device_vector`. You can use it directly in `newKernel`.

Comment: OK. Thank you. Is there a way I can create this iterator without using a `device_vector`? I am thinking that I might get better performance without using a `device_vector`.

Comment: @Jared Hoberock: Also, how would I declare `iter` in my kernel definition? As type `double`?

Comment: Declare it the same as you did in your code: `thrust::device_vector<double>::iterator iter`

Comment: @JaredHoberock: I presume the OP means in the kernel, not in the host code. I don't think he or she understands that the value of the iterator isn't an array index, it is an array value.

Comment: @talonmies: you are correct, I read what was going on in `newKernel` wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I'm summarizing the comments by talonmies and Jared Hoberock above as well as the answer by Sebastian Dressler in a fully compilable and executable example. The code calculates, by CUDA Thrust, the index of the first element of a vector satisfying a predicate (`x<=0.` in this case), I hope it will be helpful for future readers.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct less_than_or_eq_zero
{
    __host__ __device__ bool operator() (double x) { return x <= 0.; }
};

int main(void)
{
    int N = 6;

    thrust::device_vector<float> D(N);

    D[0] = 3.;
    D[1] = 2.3;
    D[2] = -1.3;
    D[3] = 0.;
    D[4] = 3.;
    D[5] = -44.;

    thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator iter1    = D.begin();
    thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator iter2    = thrust::find_if(D.begin(), D.begin() + N, less_than_or_eq_zero());
    int d = thrust::distance(iter1, iter2);

    printf("Index = %i\n",d);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you do not use a `device_vector` in your kernel but a raw array, you have to pass it an index and not an iterator. You can obtain the index by using `thrust::distance` to calculate the distance between `dev_ptr_Col46` and `iter`.

You'll also want to read [thrust iterators](http://docs.thrust.googlecode.com/hg/group__iterators.html) documentation, where `distance` is documented.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to get this working with a normal `device_vector` but unable when I pass a `device_ptr`. When I use the following expression `int index = thrust::distance(dev_ptr_Col46, iter);` the compiler tells me that no instance of the `distance` function template matches the argument list. Is it possible to use this `device_ptr` as an argument to the `thrust::distance` function?

Comment: You have to measure iterator distances, i.e. use the `begin()` member of your `device_vector`. To use the `device_vector` on a custom kernel, you can get a raw pointer out of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 thrust::device_ptr<double> val_ptr = thrust::find_if(dev_ptr_Col46, dev_ptr_Col46 + size,less_than_or_eq_zero());
 double * val = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(val_ptr);
 newKernel<<<size, 1>>>(dev_array, val)
```

Your kernel will have to have signature

```
 __global__ void newKernel(double * dev_array, double * val)
```

Comment: look at the kernel code in the original question. how does passing a value from the array to the kernel solve the problem? the whole point of the questionis how to get the index from the iterator, not the value.

Comment: @talonmies Ok, I misread the kernel. If he needs to get index, he can do int iter = val_ptr - dev_ptr_Col46.